# How to change the RGB value of a variable in to string in SASS?

Tags: string, sass, rgb, tostring

I have been trying to change the value of a variable to string, I have read and tried some built-in SASS functions. As an example look at the code below:

```
$primary-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
$string: quote($primary-color); // => "#000000"

// But I want to have it as "rgb(0, 0, 0)".
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$primary-color` variable is known as a color type by SASS and won't save its format.
The goal is reachable by using interpolation (`#{}`) and the `sass:color` module. More information about them is available at the following links:

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#red

In the following code, statement between `#{` and `}` is a SASS code and will be processed by SASS. `red()` is a function that gets the red part number of a color; also `green()` and `blue()` are the same as `red()` function for their colors.

```
$string: "rgb(#{red($primary-color)},#{green($primary-color)},#{blue($primary-color)})"; // => "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
```